# Create file path variable without opening file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to implement some simple error logging in a PowerShell script that installs stuff.

The structure is as follows:

```
New-Item C:\Test\LogFile.txt -ItemType file
$Path = C:\Test\LogFile.txt

try
{
    #Install stuff
}
catch
{
    Add-Content $Path "error description"
}


try
{
    #Install more stuff
}
catch
{
    Add-Content $Path "error description"
}
```

The problem is with the `$Path = C:\Test\LogFile.txt` line. It's causing the file to open up. Can I create the path variable without opening the file? I really want to use a variable here in case I decide to change the error log file location.

Comment: $path = "c:\test\logfile.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's auto-opening the file because you're calling the path like you would from the shell.  If you want to see it in action, open powershell and just type the path to your error file and hit enter, it'll probably open in notepad.

To avoid this, you need to wrap the $path variable in quotes:  $path = 'c:\blah.txt'

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!